# Getting $_GET variables in other files

Tags: php

I want to get another variable in another file, but I am wondering if this will work since I am trying to get a $_GET variable. In file one (login_check_update.php):

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

And in file two:

```
else{
    include 'login_check_update.php';
?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $username; ?></b></p>
```

Would file two try and get the values in the URL on that page or will it get the previous URL in the previous page? As in will file's two $username variable be redundant and cancel each other out?

chat.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat - Customer Module</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chat.css" />
</head>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    loginForm();
}
else{
    include 'login_check_update.php';
?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $username; ?></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>    
    <div id="chatbox"></div>

    <form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is `login_check_update.php` the file you are describing as "file 1"? It's unclear.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following may help you clarify your question:

Two files, same directory.

First file, named `one.php`:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

Second file named `two.php`:

```
<?php
include 'one.php';
echo $name;
```

If I call file `two.php` with the following query param: `two.php?name=who`

This will output:

```
who
```

As `$name` is in the same scope.

Think of the include crudely as it inserting a text snippet of the first file in-place.